# /usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 4: /etc/environment: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I keep getting this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  geoip-database-extra gir1.2-ayatanaappindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-gexiv2-0.10
  libayatana-appindicator3-1 libayatana-indicator3-7 libjs-openlayers libnl-route-3-200
  libqt5multimedia5 libsmi2ldbl libwireshark-data libwireshark10 libwiretap7 libwscodecs1
  libwsutil8 python-bs4 python-certifi python-configobj python-html5lib python-httplib2
  python-lxml python-olefile python-openssl python-pil python-pycurl python-requests
  python-urllib3 python-webencodings wireshark wireshark-common wireshark-qt
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 4: /etc/environment: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output of `cat /etc/environment`:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171/bin"
    JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171
```

Answer (score 5):

You should edit your */etc/environment* with text editor and add last quote (`"`) to it.
For example with Nano:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

change

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171
```

to

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jre1.8.0_171"
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to quit.

Comment: I did the thing you said, and this is the output when I tried sudo apt-get dist-upgrade:

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
W: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (0 vs 4).
   Affected packages: install-info:amd64

Comment: Then run `sudo apt-get install -f` followed by `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: I now get N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: Try to refresh package lists with `sudo apt-get update`, and upgrade packages with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` then.

Comment: Tried that, it still didn't work.

Comment: I assume that your */etc/environment* is correct, so it is new question. Please [ask it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with all details and output.

Comment: No... I still can't install anything. That thing didn't change anything, and I don't think it's really related, I think, I don't know.