# Problems with package managers (aptitude and apt)

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

My problems in Aptitude:
I keep getting this error

`E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
W: Is the package apt-transport-http installed?`
And I can't update anything, if I'm installing I get this:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
```

or sometimes this with the log above:

```
E: Internal error: couldn't generate list of packages to download
```

And when I installed Aptitude just earlier, it uninstalled apt.

My problems with apt:

Sometimes, I can't use sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade.

I forgot the rest because I can't do it again because Aptitude uninstalled it.
PLEASE HELP ME!

Comment: Nope, Aptitude uninstalled apt, I can't do stuff with Aptitude, and I do not know how to install apt. Question is really different from that.

Comment: Maybe this one helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/830070/how-to-get-apt-back-after-uninstalling-it

Comment: Do you remember what you did before your system became too broken? Please add some details to the question. You have had [broken */etc/environment*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039962/i-cant-install-any-packages-via-terminal), we fixed it. What else?

Comment: Netbeans can't install because it cannot find Java, but BlueJ works almost flawlessly. BlueJ says: Gtk-Message: 18:58:58.044: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar", so do other apps, I also can't install some repositories and packages, here are the logs: E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/rgibert/ebook/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
P.S. It's not just that repo that has that...

Comment: I also have a lot more questions... Like how can I go back to my MacOS partition? I can mount it, move files from my MacOS partition to Ubuntu, etc. But I can't go back, I installed reFind before I dual-booted,  and I have followed Lifewire's tutorial very carefully. Or is it because I do not have a USB keyboard?

Comment: AskUbuntu guidelines ask for ONE question per post, so please create a new post for other issues.

Comment: Re-installation of apt is explained at https://askubuntu.com/questions/860375/installing-apt-get  so you can get apt back and document  how it is misbehaving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall `apt` package with one of the methods below:

- method 1 (if `aptitude` is alive)

  ```
  sudo aptitude install apt
  ```
- method 2 (if `apt-get` is alive)

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  apt-get download apt
  sudo dpkg -i apt*.deb
  ```
- method 3 (using `wget` and `dpkg`)

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.6.1_amd64.deb
  sudo dpkg -i --force-all apt*.deb
  ```

Then use `apt-get` as before:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I get this: 
dpkg: error processing archive apt_1.6.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 installing apt would break aptitude, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt_1.6.1_amd64.deb

Comment: But `sudo aptitude install apt` works?

Comment: The thing I posted above says that it's dangerous because installing apt might break aptitude, so I think I just need to uninstall aptitude. I got this with the shell command you just sent to me/the one I'm replying to, 0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,043 kB of archives. After unpacking 3,429 kB will be used.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
E: Internal error: couldn't generate list of packages to download

Comment: Try with `sudo dpkg -i --force-all apt*.deb`.